# templated abstract factory class with pooling

Tags: c++, object, factory

I'm working on a game engine component that handles events. What I'm trying to do is create a system that I can register new event types by name.  The event manager will then hold a collection of event types and the factories to generate such an event type BUT the twist is that I want to make it used a pooling system such that I create an event, use it and then rather than deleting it, throw it into a list.  Next time I create that event, rather than using the heap, I can just allocate from the pool.

SO given these hierarchy of event types...

```
struct TEvent
{
  int nID;
  int nTimeStamp;
};

struct TCollisionEvent : public TEvent
{
  TEntity* pEntity1;
  TEntity* pEntity2;
  Vector3* pvecPoint;
};
```

I then created a smart factory which does this creation/recyling operation:

```
template <class BASE_CLASS>
class CSmartFactory
{
private:
  typedef typename std::list<BASE_CLASS*> TBaseList;
  typedef typename std::list<BASE_CLASS*>::iterator TBaseListItr;

  TBaseList* m_plstPool;

public:
  explicit CSmartFactory()
  {
    m_plstPool = NULL;
  }

  ~CSmartFactory()
  {
    TBaseListItr itr;

    if (m_plstPool)
    {
      for (itr = m_plstPool->begin(); itr != m_plstPool->end(); itr++)
      {
        BASE_CLASS* pEntity = *itr;
        SAFE_DELETE(pEntity);
      }

      m_plstPool->clear();
      SAFE_DELETE(m_plstPool);
    }    
  }

  bool Init(int nPoolSize)
  {
    bool bReturn = false;

    do 
    { 
      m_plstPool = new TBaseList;
      IwAssert(MAIN, m_plstPool);

      while (nPoolSize--)
      {
        BASE_CLASS* pBaseObject = new BASE_CLASS;
        IwAssert(MAIN, pBaseObject);

        m_plstPool->push_back(pBaseObject);
      }

      bReturn = true;
    } while(0); 

    return bReturn; 
  }

  BASE_CLASS* Create()
  {
    BASE_CLASS* pBaseObject = NULL;

    //
    // grab a pre-made entity from the pool or allocate a new one
    if (m_plstPool->size() > 0)
    {
      pBaseObject = m_plstPool->front();
      m_plstPool->pop_front();
      pBaseObject->Clear();
    }
    else
    {
      pBaseObject = new BASE_CLASS;
      IwAssert(MAIN, pBaseObject);
    }

    return pBaseObject;
  }

  void Recycle(BASE_CLASS* pBaseObject)
  {
    m_plstPool->push_back(pBaseObject);
  }
};
```

SO now I can do this:

```
CSmartFactory<TCollisionEvent>* pCollisionEventFactory = new CSmartFactory<TCollisionEvent>;
```

BUT what I want to do is have my event manager allow for dynamic event registration but that's where I run into my snag.

Ideally RegisterEvent will track the name and factory pointer in an stl::map or something but not quite sure how to get to that point.  Maybe I've gone down the wrong path altogether.

This compiles

```
class TEventManager
{
public:
  TEventManager();
  ~TEventManager();

  bool RegisterEvent(char* pszEventName, CSmartFactory<TEvent>* pFactory);
};
```

Until you add

```
TEventManager::RegisterEvent("CollisionEvent", new CSmartFactory<TEntityCollisionEvent>);
```

So now I'm hopelessly trying to find a way to make this all work.

Anybody got some ideas here!?

Fred

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to reuse events to avoid expensive heap malloc/free's?

I think the right answer here is not to convolute your code by writing your own structure for reusing objects, but to use a small-object allocator. As a start, it may be worth looking into [boost::pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/pool/doc/index.html).

Comment: Correct, I very much want to avoid expensive malloc/free's.

The only issue is that this particular platform I'm working with doesn't support boost hence why I'm trying to put my own together.

I feel that I'm on the right path!

Comment: May I ask... what is your particular platform?

Comment: Working with AirPlay SDK so it's a confined system and they don't have official support for boost although some people have hacked in various pieces.

Comment: One option that I used in previous projects is to use TLSF (http://rtportal.upv.es/rtmalloc/). Might be worthwhile..?

Answer (score 0):

The two classes `CSmartFactory<TEntityCollisionEvent>` and `CSmartFactory<TEvent>` will be generated to something like

- CSmartFactory_TEntityCollisionEvent
- CSmartFactory_TEvent

They are actually two separate and unrelated classes. Trying to use them interchangeably would be unwise, although they behave the same (their type classes are polymorphic right).

Dynamic casting wont work, you could however try to use brute force casting:

```
TEventManager::RegisterEvent("CollisionEvent", 
        reinterpret_cast<CSmartFactory<TEvent>*>(new CSmartFactory<TEntityCollisionEvent>));
```

Warning: At your own risk! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

OK so after a lot of head banging, I realized the solution is FAR simpler than what I was trying to pull off.

All the manager should care about is managing a TEvent*. Each TEvent has a unique hash value that makes it unique so when a new event is added both the string name and hash name of that even is stored.  So from there I can add a pointer to any subclass so long as it's casted to TEvent.

I was making it FAR more complex than it needed to be.